# How to serialize a mac address into a BigInteger field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want my API to be able to handle mac addresses as integers as well as strings.

In my model, I have set:

```
class WifiAccessPoint(models.Model):
    bssid = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

And I have tried this:

```
def mac_address(value):
    # return integer if value is either (1) int or (2) "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
    # raises Validation error
    try:
        ret = int(value)
        return ret
    except:
        try:
            ret = int((value).replace(":", ""), 16)
            return ret
        except:
            raise ValidationError(_("Not a mac address"))


class WifiAccessPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # specify mac address field, to enable 2 forms (int and "xx:xx:xx")
    bssid = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[mac_address])
    class Meta:
        model = WifiAccessPoint
        fields = ('bssid', 'ssid', 'rssi', 'channel',)
```

But this isn't working: when I post a string mac address (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx), I get a 400 error: integer is required.

I understand that rest-framework is running a validatore before mine, but how do I override this behavior?

Tx

Comment: `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is not an integer then why do you want to use an `IntergerField`?

Comment: Because I store my mac addresses as integers.

Comment: Then you convert them? because `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is definitly not an integer. but the question is why do you want to store them as integer and not char?

Comment: @VincentLê Louis is right. The bssid is not an integer per se. It's an ID string (happened to only consist of numeric values) and should be treated like a string.

Comment: I didn't post my validator code,  but it's a function returning an int or raising ValidationError.  And I've tested,  this validator is runned,  but some other things happens next,  raising a 'not int'  error

Comment: Bssid isn't a 48bits int?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. This is a `MacIntegerField` that will automatically convert values from string MAC values to integer (has to be a 64bit system, otherwise some of MAC will be lost, since MACs are 48bits). Although I haven't tried it, it should work.

```
import re
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

MAC_GROUPS = 6
MAC_DELIMITER = ':'
MAC_RE = re.compile("([0-9a-f]{2})" +
                    ("\%s([0-9a-f]{2})" % MAC_DELIMITER) * (MAC_GROUPS - 1),
                    flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def mac2int(mac):
    match = re.match(MAC_RE, mac)
    mac_int = 0
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("Not a mac address")
        #raise ValidationError(_("Not a mac address"))
    for g in match.groups():
        mac_int = mac_int << 8
        mac_int = mac_int | int(g, 16)
    return mac_int


def int2mac(mac_int):
    mac = ""
    for n in range(MAC_GROUPS):
        mac = "{0}{1:0{2}x}{3}".format(MAC_DELIMITER, mac_int & 0xff, 2, mac)
        mac_int = mac_int >> 8
    return mac[1:]


class MacIntegerField(Field):
    MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 17
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _("Not a mac address")
    }

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MacIntegerField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.validators.append(
            RegexValidator(MAC_RE, message=self.error_messages['invalid']))


    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return mac2int(data)            
        except ValueError:
            self.fail('invalid', input=data)


    def to_representation(self, value):
        return int2mac(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the solution. 
In fact, a validator is here to **validate** the data, not changing it.

So if you want to change the string to a an integer, you have to perform this action on the creation.

Then, I need a CharField with my validator:

```
def mac_address(value):
    # return integer if value is either (1) int or (2) "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
    # raises Validation error
    try:
        # is value an integer?
        ret = int(value)
        return ret
    except:
        try:
            # value is not an integer, try to resolve a mac address
            ret = int((value).replace(":", ""), 16)
            return ret
        except:
            raise ValidationError(_("Not a mac address"))


class WifiAccessPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # specify mac address field, to enable 2 forms (int and "xx:xx:xx")
    bssid = serializers.CharField(validators=[mac_address,])

    class Meta:
        model = WifiAccessPoint
        fields = ('bssid', 'ssid', 'rssi', 'channel',)
```

This will just validate incoming data.

Then, in my create function of the serializer, I add this code:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
     wap = validated_data.pop('wifiaccesspoint')      
     wap['bssid']=mac_address(wap['bssid'])
```

**This last line of code id the key!**